How to "validate" restrictions on a service?
When using features such as RootDirectory= or ProtectSystem=full or ProtectHome= or BindReadOnlyPaths= or ReadOnlyPaths= or PrivateNetwork= or InaccessibleDirectories=, how do you validate them easily?
I tried the naive # systemd --slice myservice -S when the service is running, but I get a root shell with no restrictions. Maybe I'm not understanding the meaning of slice here, but i'm assuming it is to create scopes under the scope that defines the restrictions/cgroups/namespaces for the slice?
